# Why do lasers need mirrors at the edge of the cavity?

Tags: laser, laser-interaction, laser-cavity

If the avalanche stimulated emissions start from the first absorbtion that occurs in the cavity then why are mirrors needed? I imagine a photon that even without mirrors stimulates extra coherent emissions, provided a continuous pumping energy. I apologize from my inappropriate terminology but I'm not a physics student

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, lasers do not require mirrors nor do they require a cavity. Laser stands for light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation. The only requirement being amplification of light and that stimulated emission is the dominant effect by which it is done.

Take for example [EDFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDFA) (Erbium doped fibre pumped out of band). It is used as a repeater in long haul telecoms networks to amplify the light signal. No cavity is involved. No mirrors are involved.

A laser with mirrors are also known as losers. I.e. light oscillation by stimulated emission of radiation. Actual they do amplify, it is just the background thermal noise that they are amplifying.

Stimulated emission produces the coherency. As light is produced in reaction to the light that stimulates it, the phase is synchronised. For spontaneous emission it is merely that. Spontaneous. No phase relationship to existing light. No coherency.

Comment: [X-ray lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_laser) are another example of lasers without mirror.

Comment: Ok, then my questiton is twofold: 1) why do lasers used as optical source in fiber optic communication require mirrors (in other word, can't they do the sasme job without mirrors?) and 2) why in LED are the emissions almost all spontaneus? Thanks a lot

Comment: Lasers as a source rather than as an amplifier amplifies noise. Without mirrors you need longer lengths of costly gain medium, more pump sources to enable an even out of band absorption over its length and bulkier packaging.

Comment: An LED is just a laser that isn't lasing. The probability of stimulated emission is related to population inversion; i.e. getting molecules excited so that there are more in the high energy state than the lower.

Comment: Mirrors do allow a longer effective length than the length of the gain medium. Coherence length without morrors is limited to the length of the gain medium (not so much a problem with EDFA in optical communications). With mirrors you can make it much longer.

Comment: @PaulChilds thanks a lot! It's clear now

Answer (score 1):

Tapered amplifiers are another technology which utilizes amplification of the forward propagating mode by stimulated emission. In this technology a semi-conducting gain medium is pumped electronically (current is flowed into the device to excite charge carriers to the excited band) while laser light is shined into the input port of the device. The light propagates though the device increasing in intensity as it propagates along the optical axis until it exits the device, now amplified by multiple orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

I know physics but I'm no laser expert, but the mirrors are perfectly parallel so that gets the emissions going in the perpendicular direction. It has to do with probabilities and when the population of photons starts moving in the correct direction then they all start to move that way.  Note that while one mirror is almost 100% reflective the other is designed to be only say 90% reflective allowing 10% of the light to escape as what we see as the beam.

Comment: thanks for your answer but my doubt was another. I mean, amplification and light emission can occur alsos without mirror, then why in a led are they incoherent whereas in laser (thanks to mirror) are coherent?

Comment: Yes an led is mainly incoherent but still has a little stimulated emission.  In stimulated emission the high population of excited atoms will react (with a certain probability) to a nearby photon.  The reaction is a photon released in the same direction and time so now there are 2 photons travelling coherently, this happens more often in a small cavity with mirrors.  An LED is much larger than a laser diode.